# Why is logging behaving this way in python

Tags: python, logging

So, recently, I've experienced some weird behaviour in my project, so I did a small test to reproduce the behaviour. Here is a complete code:

```
import logging
from logging import config

config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'fmt_root':    {'format': '[ /        ] - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'},
        'fmt_pkg':     {'format': '[ /pkg     ] - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'},
        'fmt_pkg_sub': {'format': '[ /pkg/sub ] - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'},
    },
    'handlers': {
        'hnd_root': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'formatter': 'fmt_root',
        },
        'hnd_pkg': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'formatter': 'fmt_pkg',
        },
        'hnd_pkg_sub': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'formatter': 'fmt_pkg_sub',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['hnd_root'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG,
    },
    'loggers': {
        'pkg': {
            'handlers': ['hnd_pkg'],
            'level': logging.WARNING,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'pkg.sub': {
            'handlers': ['hnd_pkg_sub'],
            'level': logging.INFO,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
})

logging.getLogger().info('message 1')
logging.getLogger('pkg').info('message 2')
logging.getLogger('pkg.sub').info('message 3')
```

Output of this small program is:

```
[ /        ] - INFO - root - message 1
[ /pkg/sub ] - INFO - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /pkg     ] - INFO - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /        ] - INFO - pkg.sub - message 3
```

Now, this isn't the output that I would naturally expect. Why is "message 2" not logged on root logger (message level is info, root accepts debug level) and why is "message 3" logged on 'pkg' logger (message level is info, pkg accepts warning)?

I did some research and I found that the message level is only checked against the logger the message was posted to directly - all parent logger levels up to a root are not checked, only their handler levels are checked. **This seems odd to me. Is there an explanation of this? Why does it behave this way? What are the use cases for this?**

PS: The behaviour I was expecting from this code was the exact thing I would get if I switched handler and logger levels around:

```
[ /        ] - INFO - root - message 1
[ /        ] - INFO - pkg - message 2
[ /pkg/sub ] - INFO - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /        ] - INFO - pkg.sub - message 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger's level is used first, as a go/no go check. This is because you can have multiple handlers for a logger. For example, you could have a [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) that writes to disk `INFO` and above and a [SMTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler) that only emails `CRITICAL`.
If it passes that check then the log is sent to the loggers handlers, and when propagate is set to `True`, it's also sent to the handlers of the parent loggers of the log you called, ignoring the level check in those loggers.

This way, `message 2` will not be printed at all, because it does not pass the logger's level check, but `message 3` will print 3 times, because that logger is set for a lower level than `INFO'`, and the handlers for `\`, `pkg` and `pgk.sub` are set at a lower level than `INFO`.

In short, the logger level means "Should I send this to the handlers?" and the handler level means "Should I write this to disk/console/socket etc.?".

Example 1.

```
Logger  | Logger level | Handler Level
/       | CRITICAL     | DEBUG
pkg     | CRITICAL     | DEBUG
pkg.sub | DEBUG        | DEBUG
```

Using `logging.getLogger('pkg.sub').debug('message 3')` will print :

```
[ /pkg/sub ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /pkg     ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /        ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
```

Example 2.

```
Logger  | Logger level | Handler Level
/       | CRITICAL     | INFO
pkg     | CRITICAL     | DEBUG
pkg.sub | DEBUG        | DEBUG
```

Using `logging.getLogger('pkg.sub').debug('message 3')` will print :

```
[ /pkg     ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /        ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
```

Example 3.

```
Logger  | Logger level | Handler Level
/       | CRITICAL     | DEBUG
pkg     | CRITICAL     | INFO
pkg.sub | DEBUG        | DEBUG
```

Using `logging.getLogger('pkg.sub').debug('message 3')` will print :

```
[ /pkg/sub ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
[ /        ] - DEBUG - pkg.sub - message 3
```

In order to get the result you want, you need this setup :

```
Logger  | Logger level | Handler Level
/       | DEBUG        | DEBUG
pkg     | INFO         | WARNING
pkg.sub | INFO         | DEBUG
```